# Json conversion to double and bind to WPF nummericupdown fails

Tags: json, wpf, vb.net, binding, mahapps.metro

Currently i get an error on a binding. The situation is that i write my settings to a JSON file. When the app opens again the JSON file is read and used throughout the application. Now there's a strange thing: When i bind a double value to the value of a nummericupdown than i get an error: `type 'JValue' to type 'System.Nullable1[System.Double]'for 'en-US'` however this error doesn't occur when i recreate the JSON list and file. (simply said when i delete the file and restart the app it will create a new instance of a class en write it to disk)

Property in class:

```
Public Property SomeValue As Double
```

Write/Reader JSON:

```
'Write
Using _file As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(SettingFilePath)
            Dim serializer As New JsonSerializer()
            serializer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented
            serializer.Serialize(_file, Me)
End Using

'Read
Return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Settings)(File.ReadAllText(settingsfile))
```

JSON string:

```
"SomeValue": 1.0,
```

Binding in XAML:

```
<Controls:NumericUpDown
                Width="200"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                Maximum="5"
                Minimum="1"
                NumericInputMode="All"
                Speedup="false"
                Value="{Binding SomeValue}" />
```

Please note that i use the Mathapps Metro nummericupdown control version 1.6.5

Newtonsoft version 10.0.0.1 (Cannot update due to dependencies)

**Edit:**

As asked i digged deeper and now know where it starts, but don't know yet how to resolve it. Is start with my class for example:

```
Public class Hello    
   Dim a as Object
   Dim b as EnumTypeOfObjectIn_A
   Dim SomeOtherStuff as String    
End class
```

Now when i `DeserializeObject` de file to the Class `Hello` then variable `a` becomes a object of type `JObject` and this is why alot of logica afterwords goes wrong. When i create the object in code everything goes well because the `TypeOf` object matches the one i put in. So is there a work arround for the `Deserializer` to convert the object to the one that is indicated in variable `b` ?

Comment: Your issue is not reproducible based on the information you have supplied. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution i was looking for. The `Newtonsoft JSON` contains the `JsonSerializerSettings` class that helps the de/serialization process. For me it is important to add the Type of object when serializing so that's exactly what     `TypeNameHandling` and `TypeNameAssemblyFormatHandling` is for in the `Newtonsoft JSON` assembly

I ended up with this code:

```
Public Class Hello

    Public Property A As Object
    Dim settingsfile As String = "C:\jsontest.json"

    Public Sub Save()

        Using _file As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(settingsfile)
            _file.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Me, Formatting.Indented, New JsonSerializerSettings() With {
                                                .TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects,
                                                .TypeNameAssemblyFormatHandling = TypeNameAssemblyFormatHandling.Simple
                                                }))
        End Using
    End Sub

    Public Function Load() As Hello
        Return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Hello)(File.ReadAllText(settingsfile), New JsonSerializerSettings() With {.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects})
    End Function
End Class

Public Class Person
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Age As Integer

    Sub New()
        Me.Name = "John"
        Me.Age = 130
    End Sub
End Class
```

Producing this JSON output, note the `$Type`

```
{
  "$type": "MyNamespace.Hello, MyNamespace",
  "A": {
    "$type": "MyNamespace.Person, MyNamespace",
    "Name": "John",
    "Age": 130
  }
}
```